# How to Manage Scheduled Task in Win XP Professional

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I created a exe in c# .Net 2005.
Scheduled it to run on the server every day at 10 AM.
But I can not close the exe when intended task is completed so it remains open and Task Schedular shows its status as running as it is also plesent in Task Manager and When next day its run time come to run then it dosen't run.

At first time only it runs properly (When its in not running in Schedular) but if it is running then again exe is not runnoing.
I also set the option 'Stop Task if it runs 1 Hr' in 'Setting' in task schedular but this option also not stop running exe through schedular.

Can you please tell how should I schedule exe using windows Task Schedular so that it will run every day.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your C# application is a Windows Forms app or not. But if it is you may try to call `Application.Exit()` method at the end of execution.

Comment: It is Winform exe. and I can not use Application.Exit() asit will close the application I wants it shpould be open as given option for user interaction once form opens.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If the application is not closed it will remain as a running task. I thought you want it closed before the scheduler calls it next time.